# Is it possible to execute all statements under a set of other targets under a given target in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have just started learning to use `make` and I have a query regarding statements that can be executed under a given target.

> Is it possible to execute all statements under a set of other targets under a given target in GNU make?

For example,

```
target1: dependency1
    statement1
target2: dependency2
    statement2
```

I now want to write a new target, `target3`, that will execute all statements in both `target1` and `target2`, which in this case, will execute both `statement1` and `statement2`. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `target3` to be *nothing but* `target1 + target2`. You would
do that like:

```
.PHONY: target3

target3: target1 target2

target1: dependency1
    statement1
target2: dependency2
    statement2
```

See [4.6 Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!